# How to configure Spring Security for dynamic number of users

Tags: spring-security, passwords

If your website only handles just one user name and one password, what you need to write in `application.properties` can be pretty simple and static as the following.

```
spring.security.user.name=user
spring.security.user.password=password
```

But what about a situation where the website handles multiple users? I mean, the website allows new users to create new accounts, which means that the number of user names and passwords can dynamically change. It can be 100 users, 5000 users or possibly any other number.

In this kind of scenario, how do you manage user names and passwords? (Of course the passwords are to be stored in an encrypted form, not in a form of plain text)